# Custom DNS On Kubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: dns, free

I wrote to you this because I have try to make kubuntu use quad 9 DNS or Cloudflare or other DNS but not working I have try with `rezolv.conf` with configure network connection under  with automatic (only address) with stubby. All work after reboot but after some minute reverse to original DNS delivered by my ISP.
All the best to you!

Sorry for my bad English if any.

In my case not working i am on kubuntu and wifi.
Thank you for answers.
All the best but maybe you see my network settings are on kubuntu.

[kubuntu network connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWIEB.png)

Comment: https://pchelp.ricmedia.com/set-custom-dns-servers-linux-network-manager-resolv-conf/

Comment: Try it via network manager. It will work.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

Open your network connection profile. Set IPv4 Method to Auto, DNS Automatic to off (0), and enter a comma-separated list of DNS servers in the DNS field.

[image]